# Using single, double and triple quotes in SQL for text qualifiers

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I am processing some CSV data from a client and one of the headers is 'booktitle'. The values of 'booktitle' are text qualifed with double quote and there are quotes in some of the titles, such as;

```
"How to draw the "Marvel" way"
```

I asked the client to escape the quotes in quotes with double quotes, and they sent me back this

```
'"How to draw the """Marvel""" way "'
```

So single, double, then triple quote. My question is will this work? I have not seen it done this way before for escaping text qualifiers.

Comment: What is the issue here? Do you want to escape the single quotes?

Comment: Will what work? Are you trying to stop the double-quotes inside the values confusing your parsing of the CSV? Are they actually causing you a problem? It would probably help to show how you're parsing it, and why these are an issue. At the moment it isn't clear if you are just confused about the difference between single quotes, escaped single quotes, and double-quotes.

Comment: Do not assume for any issue. Process the csv file if any issue occurs then share it.

Answer (score 0):

Which way are you using to save the info?

If you are saving it directly from SQL, double quotes are not a problem as SQL use single quotes.
If you are using a program, use SqlParameters. It will wrap you everything

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKS(
  ID    INT,
  TITLE VARCHAR2(4000)
);
```

**CSV**:

```
ID,TITLE
1,"How to draw the ""Marvel"" Way"
2,"Test ""Someone's Data"""
```

*(One double quote at start and end, two double quotes to escape a double quote in the middle of the string and single quotes don't need to be escaped.)*

**Import via Oracle SQL Developer**

1. In the connections pane, right click the table name and select "Import Data..."
2. Browse and select the CSV file then the default values will be sufficient so click "Next >".
3. Set the Import Method to "Insert" and deselect "Send Create Script to SQL Worksheet" then click "Next >" three times.
4. Click "Finish" and the data will be imported.